# Select rows / columns as displayed using HTML + CSS only

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to select rows and / or columns in an element as displayed using HTML + CSS only?

Sample:

HTML:

```
<div id="long">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>    

<div id="short">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { font-family: courier; }
div div { display: inline-block; }

#long, #short { margin: 1em; }
#long { width: 4em; border: 1px solid red; }
#short { width: 2em; border: 1px solid blue; }
```

jsFiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/j6gbL0c4/1/

Say this gets displayed like this:

[image]

I'd like to apply a style to columns as displayed. E.g. if I want to style the 2nd column in the red rectangle, I'd like to select elements 2, 5 and 8. For 2nd row of blue rectangle, I'd like to select elements 3 and 4.

I do not know the number of elements in a row / column, that depends on the width of the rectangle, which is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [nth_child selection in css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)
For what you want to achieve in

```
    <div id="long">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </div>    

    <div id="short">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
    </div>
```

now for 2,5 and 8 from `#long`

```
#long div:nth-child(2),#long div:nth-child(5),#long div:nth-child(8)
{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

for 3 and 4 from `#short`

```
#short div:nth-child(3),#short div:nth-child(4)
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Hope it helps!